# This loop is executing more iterations than is expected

Tags: c++

I am having problems with the following code. What I expect is for the `do-while` loop to execute 4 times, once for each line of the text file it is reading in, but in reality is it executing five time, which is resulting in a segfault later in the program. What am I doing wrong here that's causing it to execute the extra iteration? I've tried replacing he `do-while` with a simple `while` loop but the result is the same.

```
int count = 0;
string devices[4];
string line;
ifstream DeviceList;
DeviceList.open("devices/device_list.txt");
do
{
 getline(DeviceList, line);
 devices[count] = line;
 count ++;
} while(!DeviceList.eof());
```

`device_list.txt` contains the following:

```
WirelessAdaptor
GPU
CPU
Display
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no whitespaces (blank lines in particular) at the end of your input file? Use a debugger (or just `cout`) to examine the value of `line` in each step.

Comment: Does the 4th line of the your .txt file ("Display") end with a carriage return / newline?  If so, you really have an extra (empty) line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eof()` doesn't return true until `getline` consumes the end.  It doesn't do this until the `getline` call *after* reading the last line.  You need to check if `eof` is true immediately after your `getline` call:

```
while(true)
{
  getline(DeviceList, line);
  if(DeviceList.eof())
    break;
}
```

Comment: Fred's version is better and accounts for more than just eof.

Comment: Agreed.  Checking `eof` is more useful if there is behavior specific to reaching the end of file.  You may want to throw an exception on failure but continue on eof, for example.

Comment: @Noah: It didn't account for empty lines, though, until my edit.

Answer (score 5):

I think your loop should probably look more like this:

Edit: Added check to ignore empty lines

```
while (getline(DeviceList, line))
{
    if (line.length() > 0)
    {
        devices[count] = line;
        ++count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

eof() won't return true until you attempt to read more data than there is left.

Answer (score 0):

Above the line `getline(DeviceList, line);` insert `cout << line.length() << endl;` and tell us what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your text file probably contains a line feed after the last line, so `getline` reads an empty string before the loop actually ends.